# mvc 4 template in visual.studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Hi I have mvc4 template installed on my system as I had visual studio 2010 installed before and have even used it. Now I had to uninstall visual studio 2010 and upgrade to visual studio 2012 but the mvc4 template doesnt show every time I search for it for creating a MVC4 website. Please help what to do about it.

Comment: Are you trying to create a "new website" or a "new project"? If you go `File » New » Website` the MVC4 templates won't show. the templates show on `File » New » Project`

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong I was trying with File » New » Project I reinstalled everything now it shows.